# SparkSQL does not work with Hive UDAF

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hive, emr

I am using AWS EMR + Spark 1.6.1 + Hive 1.0.0

I have this UDAF and have included it in the classpath of spark https://github.com/scribd/hive-udaf-maxrow/blob/master/src/com/scribd/hive/udaf/GenericUDAFMaxRow.java

And registered it in spark by sqlContext.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION maxrow AS 'some.cool.package.hive.udf.GenericUDAFMaxRow'")

However, when I call it in Spark in the following query

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW_1 AS
      SELECT
        a.A,
        a.B,
        maxrow ( a.C,
                 a.D,
                 a.E,
                 a.F,
                 a.G,
                 a.H,
                 a.I
            ) as m
        FROM
            table_1 a
        JOIN
            table_2 b
        ON
                b.Z = a.D
            AND b.Y  = a.C
        JOIN dummy_table
        GROUP BY
            a.A,
            a.B
```

It gave me this error

```
16/05/18 19:49:14 WARN RowResolver: Duplicate column info for a.A was overwritten in RowResolver map: _col0: string by _col0: string
16/05/18 19:49:14 WARN RowResolver: Duplicate column info for a.B was overwritten in RowResolver map: _col1: bigint by _col1: bigint
16/05/18 19:49:14 ERROR Driver: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 16:32 Invalid column reference 'C'
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 16:32 Invalid column reference 'C'
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genAllExprNodeDesc(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10643)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genExprNodeDesc(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10591)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genSelectPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:3656)
```

But if I removed the group by clause and the aggregate function it worked. So I doubt that SparkSQL somehow does not think it as a aggregate function.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I found out the only when put into a CREATE VIEW statement the UDAF does not work. Using it alone in a SELECT statement is fine.